# Be able to scroll RecyclerView behind Keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I want to be able to scroll a `RecyclerView` behind a keyboard. The issue is that if I have say more than 5 items in the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, and assume that each item might have a height of say `100dp`. I want to be able to scroll the `RecyclerView` down with the keyboard still up and be able to scroll down to be able to see the first item in the `RecyclerView`.

In iOS you can set something called a `contentInset` on a `NSTableView` and that gives you extra scrolling space below the list. I am looking for something similar for the `RecyclerView` so far, there isn't much to go on.

---

**INITIAL STARTING POINT**

[image: Initial Starting]

---

**WHAT HAPPENS** (Can't scroll down anymore)

[image: WHAT HAPPENS]

---

**WHAT I WANT** (be able to scroll down)

[image]